# How to store multiple records in single column using python and postgresql?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

Was going through calorie counter made with django. there are two columns each store multiple records like

```
if food.weight==100 gram:
    calorie will be 56
    fat will be something..
    sugar will be something 


if  food.weight==1tbsp:
    calorie will be 2
    fat will be something..
    sugar will be something 
    
if  food.weight == 1oz:
    calorie will be 0  
    fat will be something..
    sugar will be something
```

means multiple data are being stored in single column (food.weight) and those data  are related to other data of other column (calorie/fat/sugar)

(i think similar results can be found with number of relational table
, like if i create a separate model for each type of food.weight )

How can i achieve this. I am a new django learner developed some initial projects.

Please suggest what  i need to learn to solve this above mentioned problem...(I am learning python and django)

Comment: I'd have an Ingredient model that stores the nutritional values (energy, fat, sugar, carbs, what-have-you) per 100g, and maybe also density (to convert from volume such as liters to weight).

Comment: Don't do that. Store only a single value in each column. Use several tables with foreign key constraints between them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store multiple attributes in a single column of a table, then one method is to use JSON data type for that column and store multiple related values.

I found a link to a similar question and answer. Therefore not rewriting the answer.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/268365/using-python-to-insert-json-into-postgresql

Another solution is to store the data in XML type with XML data type in the table.

Comment: Not a good idea, though – columns are there for a reason.